# Error EXCEPTION ACCESS VIOLATION. Blender is crashing at startup, even though it's the latest version

Tags: error

Blender is crashing at startup,  even though it's the latest version.

One of the solutions worked temporarily and then the problem came back. I tried to add something to Environmental Variables which actually worked just for a bit then on the next try to open Blender it crashed again. My video card is updated plus I tried running Blender through CMD and I tried running it as administrator. All FAILED.

The error on CMD shows is as follows:

Error EXCEPTION ACCESS VIOLATION
...

Comment: Try using the zip version, not the install one.

Comment: So I uninstall this one n then I download the zip version from the official site?

Comment: I tried it it didn't work